# Accessing role ID through module

Tags: yii

Im quite stuck here. In my cwebuser I've already defined my roles. My logins to my modules are restricted by roles, which is great! But my problem is restricting the modules to specific users within the roles. In webuser isShop is defined as a certain user id (user_role_id) in database to see if the user is user or shop. The issue is shop module can be seen by all roles who are isShop. My question is is there a way to authorize so that shop module gets user's id and shop id?

Something that mimics `yii::app()->user->user_id;`
 like `yii::app()->getmodule(shop)->shop_id;`

Or must this be defined in model through criteria by shop_id? Doesn't sound right though, doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are using the following function in model, you can apply the SHOP relations in here

```
public function defaultScope() {         
      if(isset(yii::app()->user->user_id)) return array('condition'=>'');
      // here you can apply your conditions with the relation feilds 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im not quite understanding it and sorry for the novice questions. I am looking to have the entire module for stores accessible by their store ids. If i did that, wouldn't my entire app get filtered?

Comment: the login user's roles can control in the `defaultScope()` function.

Comment: once you specified the condition for the role, its apply to all the controllers which are using the model `example: array('condition'=>'user_role_id=3'); //role id 3 is only for shop`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I already have a way to check if the user isShop or whatever role he/she is. The problem is the shop_id, not user_role_id. Looking for something like the module takes in the shop_id and pass it to the controller... and the model only takes only that shop_id.

Comment: i did try something like this 'condition'=>"store_id='".$store_id."'", doesn't work

Comment: i got it! Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!!! Very much appreciated and thanks for your patience!